# Form Validation Not Working CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function blog_create()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", 'Email', "trim|required|valid_email|max_length[100]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required|min_length[8]");
    $blog_name = $this->input->post('name');
    $blog_des = $this->input->post('description');
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
        $pass = $this->Blog_Model->blog_insert($blog_name,$blog_des,$user_id);
        if ($pass === TRUE) {
             $this->session->set_flashdata('blogin','Blog Was Inserted');
             return redirect('dashboard?success="success"');

        }

    }
    redirect('dashboard?rr="error"');
}
```

Form validation is not working i don't know what wrong
i've put validation_error in my index file but it still
does'nt show any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I created a demo with your code and it worked for me. The problem here as I see should be that you're not printing the `success` or `error` message in the `view`. I've written the code below and done the explaining in the comments wherever necessary. See if it helps you. 
**View(Blog Form)**

```
<?php $this->load->view('your-path/vwError'); // load a view to show errors ?> 

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('form'); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" > 
</form>
```

**View(Error)**

```
if($this->session->flashdata('message')){
    $message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
}

if($this->session->flashdata('error')){
    $error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
}

<?php if (!empty($message)): ?>
<div class="alert alert-success"> <!-- your-style-here, I've used bootstrap here(Green background) -->
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (!empty($error)): ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger"> <!-- your-style-here, I've used bootstrap here(Red background) -->
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <?php echo $error; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Controller**

```
function form(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("email", 'Email', "trim|required|valid_email|max_length[100]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "Password", "trim|required|min_length[8]");

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){  // validation successful

        // get the value if the validation is successful otherwise it's just extra code
        $blog_name = $this->input->post('name');
        $blog_des = $this->input->post('description');
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $pass = $this->Blog_Model->blog_insert($blog_name,$blog_des,$user_id); // your-logic

        if ($pass === TRUE) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Blog Was Inserted');

            redirect('your-url-here');

        } // you can also set a flashdata here in {else} condition if the data isn't saved ie returns FALSE
    }else{  // validation failed

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors()); // store the validation errors in flashdata

        $this->load->view('your-blog-form-view');   // You probably don't want to redirect as you'd want to retain the previous input value from the user.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first debug your code and tell me if validation is running properly or not

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  echo validation_errors();     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking:

```
If($this->form_validation->run() == true)
{
   // Do what needs to be done when validation passes
}
```

Try checking the opposite:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
{
  // Do something if validation fails
}

else
{
   // Do what needs to be done when validation passes
 }
```

In most loosely-typed language, something that is not `false` not necessarily is `true`. The form validation is guaranteed to respond `false` if validation fails but you must not assume, based on that fact alone, that a successful validation will respond `true`